# Can't do pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I need to do a pagination of the data I retrieve from the DB but I get this error:

Call to undefined method App\Models\DataFromRasp::table()

I followed the Laravel documentation but I still getting this error

My controller is this:

```
class DeviceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data=Device::all();
        return view('backend.auth.user.device', compact("data"));

    }

    public function create()
    {
        
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
    }

    public function show(Device $deviceID)
    {
        $device = Device::firstWhere('id', $deviceID);
        return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("device"));
    }

    public function edit(Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy(Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    public function visualizeData()
    {
        $data=DataFromRasp::table('data_from_rasp')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary', compact("data"));
    }

    public function getData(Request $request)
    {   
        $m_data = $request->get('m_data');
        $r_data = $request->get('r_data');
        DataFromRasp::create(['MAC' => $m_data, 'RSSI' => $r_data]);
        if(($m_data == 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E' or $m_data == '70:1C:E7:E4:71:DA') and Device::where('MAC_ADDR', $request->m_data)->doesntExist()){ 
            Device::create(['MAC_ADDR' => $m_data]);
        } 
    }

    public function scan()
    {
        $process = new Process(['python2','C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py']);
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) { throw new ProcessFailedException($process); }
        return redirect()->route('dict');
    }
}
```

The route is:

```
Route::get('dict', [DeviceController::class, 'visualizeData'])->name('dict');
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You don't get to pick the table when using a model query. The table is determined by the model. Doing `DataFromRasp::simplePaginate(10)` should be enough

Comment: Many thanks, it works...and for visualize the other data in other page how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$data = DataFromRasp::paginate(10)`

Comment: Many thanks, it works...and for visualize the other data in other page how can i do?
I need to create other pages and link the data with the number of page?